# Output of Range Slider into text input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why is the text field completely empty upon load and stays empty regardless of my slider value?

Subquestion: Should they be linked? If I enter a value in the input text field, should the slider move accordingly?

```js
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange"); 
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value; 
    slider.oninput = function() 
    { output.innerHTML = this.value; }
```

```css
   .slidecontainer { width: 100%; } 

    .slider { -webkit-appearance: none; width: 100%; height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3; outline: none; opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s; transition: opacity .2s; }
 
    .slider:hover { opacity: 1; } 

    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb { -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none; width: 25px; height: 25px; background:
    #4CAF50; cursor: pointer; } 

    .slider::-moz-range-thumb { width: 25px; height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
 <div class="slidecontainer"> 
    <input type="range" min="1000" max="5000000"
    value="250000" class="slider" id="myRange"> 
    <input type="text" id="demo" value=""> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code as below

Use `.value` instead `innerHTML` and use  `oninput="myFunction(this)"` to `#slide`

```js
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange"); 
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.value = slider.value; 
    function myFunction(x) {
    output.value = x.value;
}
```

```css
   .slidecontainer { width: 100%; } 

    .slider { -webkit-appearance: none; width: 100%; height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3; outline: none; opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s; transition: opacity .2s; }
 
    .slider:hover { opacity: 1; } 

    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb { -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none; width: 25px; height: 25px; background:
    #4CAF50; cursor: pointer; } 

    .slider::-moz-range-thumb { width: 25px; height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer"> 
    <input type="range" min="1000" max="5000000" oninput="myFunction(this)"
    value="250000" class="slider" id="myRange"/> 
    <input type="text" id="demo" value=""/> 
</div>
```

**Subquestion:**

Use `onchange="setSlider(this)"` when change `#demo` the slide will move when you click `Enter` or out from `#demo`

```js
        var slider = document.getElementById("myRange"); 
        var output = document.getElementById("demo");
        output.value = slider.value; 
        function myFunction(x) {
        output.value = x.value;
    }
           function setSlider(x) {
         slider.value= x.value;
    }
```

```css
       .slidecontainer { width: 100%; } 

        .slider { -webkit-appearance: none; width: 100%; height: 25px;
        background: #d3d3d3; outline: none; opacity: 0.7;
        -webkit-transition: .2s; transition: opacity .2s; }
     
        .slider:hover { opacity: 1; } 

        .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb { -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none; width: 25px; height: 25px; background:
        #4CAF50; cursor: pointer; } 

        .slider::-moz-range-thumb { width: 25px; height: 25px;
        background: #4CAF50; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer"> 
        <input type="range" min="1000" max="5000000" oninput="myFunction(this)"
        value="250000" class="slider" id="myRange"/> 
        <input type="text" id="demo" value="" onchange="setSlider(this)"/> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Value is normally used for input/form elements. innerHTML is normally used for div, span, td and similar elements.
For input change you can bind on change event on input obj

```
 var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.value = slider.value;    // input have value not innerhtml
    slider.oninput = function() {
      output.value = this.value;
  }


output.addEventListener("change", function() {
    slider.value = this.value;
 });
```